# What is causing the corruption of text fields with ¿ characters?

Tags: asp.net, encoding, oracle10g, character-encoding

We have a very strange problem in out application, all of a sudden we started noticing 
upside down question marks being saved along with other text typed in to the fields on the screen. These upside down question marks were not originally entered by the users and it is unclear where they come from. We are using Oracle 10g with Asp.Net.

Here is an example of the issue: "140, 141) ¿ 16-Oct-07". If any one have seen this before and found a way to fix this please let me know how.

Comment: Just checked and the NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is set to AL16UTF16

Comment: you should check NLS_CHARACTERSET not NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET settings. The difference is that NLS_CHARACTERSET controls the character set used to encode CHAR and VARCHAR2 columns and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET controls the character set used to encode NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 columns.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a character encoding issue. Please check what encoding your database (tables) are set to, and what encoding the objects or strings which are passing data in the database are of. If there is a mis-match (DB in ANSI, App in UTF-8), these sorts of issues can appear.

Answer (score 2):

Greg, you should check NLS_CHARACTERSET not NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET settings. And I bet you it's WE8ISO8859P1 or something similar and not unicode. The problem occurs when the submitted data in unicode, which is probably UTF8, and Oracle tries to map the characters to WE8ISO8859P1 character set. It does fine for most of them but fails for high ASCII number characters, like 140.

So yes, I have seen the same issue in our application and in our case it was caused by special quote marks (“example”, ‘example’) that were copied from MS Word. Word automatically converts double quotes to some other quotes. The solution was to convert the database to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

IF your users are copying from MS Word you can turn the feature off . Its part of the autocorrect/autoformat functionality. If you uncheck the replace options for quotes and apostrophes you should be ok. Be sure turn off the replacements in both the AutoFormat and AutoFormat as you type.